# Hadoop. About file creation in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

[I read that](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_user_guide.html#Checkpoint+Node) whenever the client needs to create a file in HDFS (The Hadoop Distributed File System), client's file must be of 64mb. **Is that true?** *How can we load a file in HDFS which is less than 64 MB?* Can we load a file which will be just for reference for processing other file and it has to be available to all datanodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I read that whenever the client needs to create a file in HDFS (The Hadoop Distributed File System), client's file must be of 64mb.

Could you provide the reference for the same? File of any size can be put into HDFS. The file is split into 64 MB (default) blocks and saved on different data nodes in the cluster.

> Can we load a file which will be just for reference for processing other file and it has to be available to all datanodes?

It doesn't matter if a block or file is on a particular data node or on all the data nodes. Data nodes can fetch data from each other as long as they are part of a cluster.

Think of HDFS as a very big hard drive and write the code for reading/writing data from HDFS. Hadoop will take care of the internals like 'reading from' or 'writing to' multiple data nodes if required.

Would suggest to read the following [1](http://storageconference.org/2010/Papers/MSST/Shvachko.pdf) [2](http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg15171.html) [3](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html) on HDFS, especially the 2nd one which is a comic on HDFS.

Comment: Nice comic; +1 just for that :)

Comment: Extremely nice comic I would say. And fun :)

Comment: thanks a lot...i just read somewhere whenever client completes 64mb then only he/she writes to HDFS..i got some more questions on HDFS will you help me ?

Comment: You might be referring to this `The DataNodes form a pipeline, the order of which minimizes the total network distance from the client to the last DataNode. Bytes are pushed to the pipeline as a sequence of packets. The bytes that an application writes first buffer at the client side. After a packet buffer is filled (typically 64 KB), the data are pushed to the pipeline.`. You can post in SO or mail me directly.

Comment: there isn't one for MR - why don't u start it :)

Comment: ohk i will definitely do it once i will know it fully :D..i tried to mail you but it failed

Comment: can you suggest me some more comics on hadoop??

Comment: Really go through some articles - although comics are good :) coming to your answer I don't have any.

Comment: chhaya.vishwakarma@lntinfotech.com